# RGB-Value to int

Tags: c#, colors, rgb

I've got a fairly simple problem (I hope):

I have a color:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(100, 150, 200);
```

And now I want to store say the R-Value of this color in an integer.

I tried to find this on google but I didn't really know what to search for. So I hope anyone can tell hwhat I need here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value will be accessible from the  [`R`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.r.aspx) member of [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx): `Color.R`. In the same way the `G` will get the green value, `B` the blue and `A` the alpha.

These are `byte`s, so you can always cast to `int` if needed.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for.  I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

The `R`, `G` and `B` properties gives you the color components of the `Color` value. The compontent values are bytes, so you can assign one to an `int` variable without problems:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(100, 150, 200);
int red = c.R; // will be 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

RGBA (255, 255, 255, 255) 
 = rgba( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
 = 0xFFFFFFFF

Color.R = Color.G = Color.B = Color.A = 255 = 1.0 = 0xff